# IE is not centering text in a table cell

Tags: css, internet-explorer, text-alignment

I'm going off my rocker with IE/CSS problems! I've tried everything (I think) is imaginable to center the text of a table cell. I started with the old, archaic method:

```
<tr>
    <th width="100" align="center" class="centerme">Some text here.</th>
</tr>
```

Then, I tried CSS:

```
.centerme {text-align:center;margin:0 auto;}
```

Then I tried putting the style inline (keeping ALL the other methods already mentioned):

```
<tr>
    <th width="100" align="center" class="centerme" style="text-align:center;">Some text here.</th>
</tr>
```

What could I possibly be missing? I tried center aligning the `<tr>` element, which shouldn't make a difference, but then IE is a nightmare to get along with! Note this is **only** a problem in IE. It is fine in every other browser (and this is IE 8)

Comment: No reproducable problem was presented. You should have posted a complete document that actually causes the problem in the named browser. The posted code, completed to create a minimal HTML document, does not do that.

Comment: I try to avoid doing that as it clutters up the screen with a lot of irrelevant muck that makes it hard for users to wade through all the code and actually extract the pertinent information. I know there are many versions of IE that do not show this problem, but it is most definitely reproducible!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Removing the `width="100"` resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
td 
{
    height: 50px; (or whatever value you want)
    width:50px;
 }

 #cssTable td 
{
    text-align:center; 
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but no, that does no good (and, yes, I swapped your `td` for my `th` -- I should mention that I **have** changed my `<th>` to `<td>` and that does not seem to be the root of any issue, either.

Comment: Can you create js fiddle ?

Comment: I missed one thing in my original post: I did not include the `width="100"` --I'm testing, now, to see if that was the problem.

Comment: Plz create js fiddle if you still need help.

Comment: Thanks, but I answered my own question. I don't know why, but setting the width messed it up!

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. I was able to get it to work.

The margin centers the table on the screen. So delete it if you do not want it to be centered.

Change the width to whatever you desire. Right now it is 100% for the whole width of the screen.

HTML:

```
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>row 1, cell 1</td>
        <td>row 1, cell 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>row 2, cell 1</td>
        <td>row 2, cell 2</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
table, th, td
{
border: none;
margin:0px auto;
text-align:center;
}

table{
width:50%;
}
```

Comment: Refresh this page and refer to my edits. I changed border to none in the css to get rid of the border. I was able to get it working with IE 8

Comment: Okay, but are you saying that the only way to get it to center in a cell is to center the table on the page? My page is a **bit** more complex than that, and I don't really have the freedom to move the table around. Is there some logical reason why IE is doing this? With both align="center" and style="text-align:center;" there is simply no reason at ALL this would not center my text!

Comment: @user2518163: I don't think that's what OP wants.

Comment: No you do not have to center the whole entire table on the page. You need to get rid of margin 0px auto and it still works. The text will still be cented in the table no matter what. I just tried it and it works. If you would like me to keep refreshing my main answer, let me know and I will. I can try to fix your code specifically if you want. I am not sure why that happens I have to try it and look. Let me know what you want me to do.